# How to transfer a file from my machine to another one in the vpn using only HTML5 and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-transfer

Is it possible to move a file from my local machine to another machine in my network using HTML5 and JavaScript only? If any jQuery or JavaScript plugin available can be used for this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Install a web server and a basic PHP file upload script on both machines, and there you go. But if you want to transfer files it's better to install an (S)FTP server or use your OS's file sharing features.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean client side JavaScript embedded in a webpage: No, it isn't.

- You can select a file using an HTML file input.
- You can send that file using form submission or Ajax

However:

- You can't delete the file from the client at all.
- You can't make the destination machine do anything with the file submission.

If you were to use Node.js to run some or all of the JavaScript then:

- You could write a (non-browser based) client that could send the file and delete the local version. This wouldn't have to use HTTP, so you could use SMB or SSH to transfer it instead.
- You could write a server (such as an HTTP) to receive the file and save it to disc.

Comment: as an expansion on this: the reason javascript can't manipulate or even access files on the server is because it's a client-side script which is owned by the browser. the browser can interpret the script however it desires, and can even manipulate it if desired. if that script were capable of directly accessing files on the server, having it be manipulable on the client end would be catastrophic.

Comment: Thank you all for your reply.
It seems we need to have a service/script running on the destination machine to manipulate the file we are uploading to it. 
In this case I hope we have to create any server side script on the destination machine only, not in the client application. Am I correct? If so what would be the best approach to accomplish this?
Thanks && Best Regards

Comment: @idsTech the best (safest and easiest) solution would be to set up an FTP or SFTP server on the destination machine; you can connect to the filespace and upload files at will using features built into your operating system. if, however, you *need* to use a webpage interface, the most popular solution would be php. see [this tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php).

Comment: be aware that there are a slew of potential security holes that come from making your own solution rather than using established protocols from FTP.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Quentin is wrong in theory here, since "remote" was never mentioned. If your "other machine" has shares where you can save, you can run my example below. So YES, it is possible but it depends on file size. You can read out the params from a request with client-side code like JavaScript. File sizes acceptance defer per browser but this is tweakable with Chromium/Chrome for instance. It is even possible on some OS-es to do basic authentication by using the in URL authentication notation on the form action. So what you could do is:

- Make a UI which makes you select a file in a form with method "GET"
- On submit create a base64 encoded string with the FileReader API

Basic example without the FileReader API (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>&quot;Upload&quot; locally</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="get" action="iwillsave.html">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="file">Pick a file:</label>
                <input id="file" name="file" type="file">
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

- In your "Save" page handle the file decoding and save it with the FileSystem API

Basic example without the FileSystem API (iwillsave.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>&quot;Upload&quot; locally</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getParam(name){
       if(name=(new RegExp('[?&]'+encodeURIComponent(name)+'=([^&]*)')).exec(location.search)) return decodeURIComponent(name[1]);
    };
    window.onload = function(){
        var file = getParam('file');
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = file;
    };
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: the file's contents are encoded as a get parameter? that's clever.

Comment: i actually wasn't being sarcastic. it was a novel approach i hadn't considered, even if it isn't practical for file transferring between machines.